# Automatic Face Detection Using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, matlab-cvst

I am trying to implement automatic face detection using MATLAB. I know how to implement it using OpenCV, but i would like to do it in MATLAB.

I saw two websites on this:

1) http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11073. Firstly, this website is good and it works on neural networks. It works well witht the images that are given together with it. However, when I train the neural networks using my images, the accuracy is very bad.

2) The second is http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13716-face-eye-detection. The accuracy is bad when i test with an image of my own.

Looking for better solutions as well as suggestions on what i should do. Thanks.

Comment: how to use MATLAB code or OpenCV with android.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting with the R2012a release, the Computer Vision System Toolbox includes a [Viola-Jones based](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetectorclass.html#btaovqu) [face detector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/object-detection-and-tracking.html#btd13m8) with the `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` system object.

[image: demo]

---

### EDIT:

Since you mentioned OpenCV, how about directly using it from MATLAB. Checkout [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv) project.

Here is sample code to detect faces:

```
%# Load a face detector and an image
detector = cv.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml');
im = imread('myface.jpg');
%# Preprocess
gr = cv.cvtColor(im, 'RGB2GRAY');
gr = cv.equalizeHist(gr);
%# Detect
boxes = detector.detect(gr, 'ScaleFactor',1.3, 'MinNeighbors',2, 'MinSize',[30,30]);
%# Draw results
imshow(im);
for i = 1:numel(boxes)
    rectangle('Position',boxes{i}, 'EdgeColor','g');
end
```

It is worth mentioning that MATLAB's computer vision toolbox also uses OpenCV in its implementation..